# Flutter not showing intellij suggestion box for colours pallet in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea, dart

why don't I see this in my android studio? 
  [click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjY12.png)

I tried a lot of things. I made sure that quick documentation
 is activated but it is still not working.

Comment: update dart plugin

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug with Flutter plugin. I solved the problem by selecting the color and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>.